# Install pywin32

Tags: python, pywin32

I need to install `pywin32` library to be able to call `import win32com.client`

I downloaded `pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe` file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

But when I run the file, nothing happens. The application from which I run the program freezes and I have to terminate it.

- I have installed: Python 2.7.8 [MSC v. 1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
- System: Windows 8, 64 bit

Any idea what can be wrong and how to instal pywin32?

Comment: I have the same problem but solved after downloading pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe

Comment: Try using pip or easy_install

Comment: @himanshudua he already uses pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe

Answer (score 2):

First install pywin32:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Then you need to run the post install so navigate to your python Scrips folder something like C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts then type the command:

```
pywin32_postinstall.py -install
```

This worked for me on:

Windows 8 64 bit

Python Version 3.8

Answer (score 1):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805627#c3

> The `/reg:32` flag is needed to install a 32bit pywin32 on a 64bit OS,
>   otherwise the 32bit pywin32 installer will not find the registry key
>   and so not know where to install into.  That flag would not be
>   necessary on a 32bit Windows 8, nor if you were using a 64bit Python +
>   64bit pywin32 on a 64bit win8.

Maybe try uninstalling then re-installing with the switch..?

Answer (score 0):

Probably I had similar problems with installing `coverage` package into Python 2.7, Win8.1 x64 blocked running the distro executable (error dialog was shown). I just clicked "Show more" link (instead of "OK" button) and then clicked "Run anyway".

BTW, ActiveState Python 2.7.8 already contains pyWin32 in the distribution. This is possible workaround.